# Delete a shapefile feature without mixing up the feature IDs?

Tags: shapefile, features, geotools

If I open a (shapefile) feature source and delete a feature, something happens with the IDs (some mixup). If I close and open the shapefile again it is still mixed up. But when I close the shapefile and delete the files xxx.qix and xxx.fix and open the shapefile again, the IDs seems ok.

xxx.fix and xxx.qix files are not there originally.

I open the shapefiles with:

```
    FileDataStore store;
    try {
        store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
```

And deleting a feature like this:

```
Transaction t1 = new DefaultTransaction("transaction 1");
SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) store.getFeatureSource(layerName);
featureStore.setTransaction(t1);
filter = ff.id(fids);
featureStore.removeFeatures(filter); 
t1.commit();
```

How can I delete a feature, in a shapefile, without mixing up the IDs?

Comment: Is it the spatial index that shall be updated? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefiles (being an old and obsolete format) don't have a dedicated feature id, they just use the row number so a delete will change (some) of the ids when you close and reopen them.

Comment: But it's not enough with close and re-open, I have to delete the qix file before re-opening. Is there a way to reindex the spatial index (if it is the spatial ingex that is the problem)?

Comment: You'll need to expand on your issue (with example code) to answer that but the spatial index should be updated when you write the shapefile back out. If you delete features and then just close the file I have no idea what would happen - but probably it would be broken.